# Oracle Apex is not working after reset redo logfile

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracleapplications

In my production server i get a error "redo log read error". So i created new redo log file and clear the existing one. Now database is up and i am able to see all objects using sql*plus.

Now oracle apex is not working.

Can anyone suggest how to fix it?

Comment: What does "Apex is not working" mean?

Comment: apex page is not opening.

Comment: do you get any kind of error on the screen?

Comment: localhost refused to connect.

Comment: If you really want help for this, you should include the exact steps (code) you used when you "created new redo log file and clear the existing one". Also, have you checked the alert log for any errors?